# What (if anything) can be inferred about the way a vowel is articulated from the fact that it has well defined higher formants?

Tags: phonetics, formants

I've been experimenting with analysing vowels in Praat. Sometimes it shows a clear F4 (which seems to mean that F4 has a narrow bandwidth - I don't know whether amplitude comes into it as well) and sometimes not. The difference seems to be partly to do with nasalisation, but I suspect there is more to it than that - is there anything else that the presence or absence of a clear F4 says about how the vowel is produced?

Also, is it conceivable that the presence of a clear F4 could be part of the vowel specification? It strikes me that we may not be able to create an F4 resonance wherever we like, because the position of most of the moveable parts is dictated by the need to get F1 - F3 on target. If that's right, the frequency of the next resonator is going to depend on the shape and size of your individual vocal tract, rather than anything you can control.

Comment: I don't have good idea on your clear F4 but I'd call your attention to this: higher formants may or may not have a strong correlation to the articulation, but it must be non-linear, and I'd no surprised if the function between them is even non-monotonic according to the perturbation theory. And acoustic cue about nasalization may be more complicated due to nasal-oral coupling. By the way, the LPC method used in Praat, technically, is not suitable for any nasalized vowel since only few poles but no zeros are considered in LPC.